# Manipulating Python dictionaries to remove empty values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to remove a key/value pair if the key contains 'empty' values.

I have tried the following dictionary comprehension and tried doing it in long form, but it doesn't seem to actually do anything and I get no errors.

```
def get_Otherfiles():
    regs = ["(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)", "(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\w+)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))\s=\s(\W(.*)\W)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)"]
    combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regs) + ")"
    cred_results = []
    creds = []
    un_matched = []
    filesfound = []
    d = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.bat', '.vbs', '.ps', '.txt')):
                readfile = open(os.path.join(root, filename), "r")
                d.setdefault(filename, [])
                for line in readfile:
                    m = re.match(combined, line)
                    if m:
                        d[filename].append(m.group(0).rstrip())
                    else:
                        pass
    result = d.copy()
    result.update((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v is not None)
    print result
```

Current output:

```
{'debug.txt': [], 'logonscript1.vbs': ['strUser = "guytom"', 'strPassword = "P@ssw0rd1"'], 'logonscript2.bat': ['strUsername = "guytom2"', 'strPass = "SECRETPASSWORD"']}
```

As you can see I have entries with empty values. I'd like to remove these before printing the data.

Comment: `update` will just leave the unwanted values in, don't you want `result = dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v)` (an empty list `is not None`)?

Comment: There are no `None` values in your output.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Id like to remove the Keys with empty values. Im assuming the code Im using is looking for literal values of 'None'?

Comment: It seems like you want to filter if v is an empty string (so, just `if v`). Another way is to change the front of your regex from `(.*)` to `(.+)`.

Comment: We have a lot of silent -1'ers here! Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
            d.setdefault(filename, [])
            for line in readfile:
                m = re.match(combined, line)
                if m:
                    d[filename].append(m.group(0).rstrip())
                else:
                    pass
```

You always add `filename` as a key to the dictionary, even if you don't subsequently add anything to the resulting list. Try

```
            for line in read file:
                m = re.match(combined, line)
                if m:
                    d.setdefault(filename, []).append(m.group(0).rstrip())
```

which will only initialize `d[filename]` to an empty list if it is actually necessary to have something on which to call `append`.

Comment: You sir! deserve a medal ^_^ I knew there had to be a simple solution I couldn't see. In fact I had no idea you could do it like that :). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first matching group in your regex, `(.*)`, if the regex matches but there are no characters to match, group(0) is "", not None. So, you can filter there.

```
result.update((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if not v)
```

But you can also have your regex do that part for you. Change that first group to `(.+)` and you won't have empty values to filter out.

**EDIT**

Instead of removing empty values at the end, you can avoid adding them to the dict altogether.

```
def get_Otherfiles():
    # fixes: make it a raw string so that \s works right and
    # tighten up filtering, ... (U|u) should probably be [Uu] ...
    regs = ["(.+)\s*((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)", "(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\w+)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))\s=\s(\W(.*)\W)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)"]
    combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regs) + ")"
    cred_results = []
    creds = []
    un_matched = []
    filesfound = []
    d = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.bat', '.vbs', '.ps', '.txt')):
                readfile = open(os.path.join(root, filename), "r")
                # assuming you want to aggregate matching file names...
                content_list = d.get(filename, [])
                content_orig_len = len(content_list)
                for line in readfile:
                    m = re.match(combined, line)
                    if m:
                        content_list.append(m.group(0))
                if len(content_list) > content_orig_len:
                    d[filename] = content_list
```

Comment: Although I couldn't see how changing my regx would resolve the issue (the regx is being used to search for items in the doc, the doc gets added to the dic if it is of a certain ext not if it matches regex). I gave it a try, but unfortunately I end up with the same result.

Comment: `del((k) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v is "")` something like this?

Comment: oops, I made a mistake in the post... it should have been `if not v`. No need compare against "", just anything that is "falsy" will do (and is a bit faster).

Comment: Nope still have blank values present. From what Ive seen from others so far the update wont remove the entry. Im struggling with this as I cant find out how to check if a value is empty. Ive tried the obvious "" but no luck :(

Comment: I think something along these lines will work `del((k)(k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if not v)` but I cant get the syntax correct

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. The for loop creates a dict with filename as key and a list of the first part of a line if it matches your regex. Then, you want tp filter something out. Is it any filename that has an empty list? Is it empty values in the lists?

Comment: Im trying to remove any key and its values if the values are empty '{'debug.txt': [], 'logonscript1.vbs': ['strUser = "guytom"', 'strPassword = "P@ssw0rd1"'], 'logonscript2.bat': ['strUsername = "guytom2"', 'strPass = "SECRETPASSWORD"']}' IE the first key debug.txt has empty values. Id like this to be removed.

Comment: Final question, you index by filename, but scan a directory tree. If the same filename exists in 2 directories, you add both of those into a single entry in `d[filename']. So, `dir1\logonscript1.vbs` and `dir2\logonscript1.vbs` have one entry. Is that on purpose? - I think the solution is to build a list and insert it into the dict after you complete the inner for. You check for empty right before putting it in and never have something that should be filtered out later.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v is not None)
```

update wont remove entries ... it will only add or change

```
a = {"1":2}
a.update({"2":7})
print a # contains both "1" and "2" keys
```